# Finding minimum of the trace of the matrix equals finding maximum of the trace of the inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Let $K$ be a positive definite, symmetric matrix. Let $C$ be a nondegenerate matrix of the same order. Elements of $K$ and $C$ depend on some parameter $a.$

Is it true to say that

$$
\min_{a}{trace\Bigl(C^{-1}K(C^{-1})^T\Bigr)} =\Biggl(\max_{a}{trace\Bigl(C^{T}K^{-1}C\Bigr)}\Biggr)^{-1} ?
$$

If not, is there any relationship between these max and min?

$T$ means "transpose".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It definitely can't be equal. Let $K = \begin{bmatrix}f(a)\end{bmatrix}$ and $C = \begin{bmatrix}g(a)\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\min_a \mathop{\mathrm{trace}} \left(C^{-1}K(C^{-1})^T\right) = \frac{f(a)}{g(a)^2}$ and $\max_a \mathop{\mathrm{trace}} \left(C^T K^{-1}C\right) = \frac{g(a)^2}{f(a)}$.

To find correct relation use these equations for non-degenerate square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same order: $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and $(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, @Smylic. I see I made an error in the statement. So are they always reciprocal to each other?

Comment: No. Matrices $C^{-1}K(C^{-1})^T$ and $C^TK^{-1}C$ are mutually inverse, but traces of inverse matrices are not reciprocals, e.g. $\mathrm{tr}\, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix} = 6$ and $\mathrm{tr}\, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \mathrm{tr}\, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/3\end{pmatrix} = \frac{11}6$.

Comment: yes, I understand that, thanks. But the question was about optimization problem for matrices depending on parameter. I can't think of example when it's not the case

Comment: I think if you have only minimum of the left trace and the value of $a$ giving this minimum you can't say anything about maximum of the right trace. Let $C = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $K = \begin{pmatrix}a^2 + 2 & 0 \\ 0 & (a + 1)^2 + 1\end{pmatrix}$. It is easy to see that $\min_a a^2 + 2 + (a + 1)^2 + 1 = \min_a 2(a + \frac12)^2 + \frac72 = \frac72$ and $a = -\frac12$. On the other hand $\max_a \frac1{a^2+2} + \frac1{(a+1)^2+1} \approx 1.34625$ and $a \approx -0.882538$.

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading advice in my answer, I should realize that there is no good relation much before.